# Freeing memory as man suggests yields errors in valgrind

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I'm trying to free my struct which is initalized like this

```
MemFile *file = (MemFile *) safe_malloc(sizeof(MemFile));
        char *fileMemory = NULL;
        FILE *tmp = open_memstream(&fileMemory,&(file->usedMem));
        file->fp = tmp;
        file->buffer = fileMemory;
        file->addbuffer = &fileMemory;
        file->addfp = &tmp;
        file->isOpen = 1;
        file->next = NULL;
        file->usedMem = 0;
        file->pathname = (char *) safe_malloc((strlen(pathname)+1) * sizeof(char))
```

But valgrind,when I try to free my memory, spits out

```
==7958== Invalid write of size 8
==7958==    at 0x49118C8: _IO_mem_finish (memstream.c:131)
==7958==    by 0x4907FC0: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:57)
==7958==    by 0x10B5B0: freeFile (mem.c:419)
==7958==    by 0x10B32E: mem_remove (mem.c:367)
==7958==    by 0x10B678: mem_removeFile (mem.c:441)
==7958==    by 0x10B61D: freeMemory (mem.c:431)
==7958==    by 0x10D472: main (newserver.c:458)
==7958==  Address 0x5677cd0 is in a rw- anonymous segment
==7958== 
==7958== Invalid read of size 8
==7958==    at 0x49118D2: _IO_mem_finish (memstream.c:133)
==7958==    by 0x4907FC0: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:57)
==7958==    by 0x10B5B0: freeFile (mem.c:419)
==7958==    by 0x10B32E: mem_remove (mem.c:367)
==7958==    by 0x10B678: mem_removeFile (mem.c:441)
==7958==    by 0x10B61D: freeMemory (mem.c:431)
==7958==    by 0x10D472: main (newserver.c:458)
==7958==  Address 0x5677cd0 is in a rw- anonymous segment
==7958== 
==7958== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7958==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7958==    by 0x10B5D8: freeFile (mem.c:422)
==7958==    by 0x10B32E: mem_remove (mem.c:367)
==7958==    by 0x10B678: mem_removeFile (mem.c:441)
==7958==    by 0x10B61D: freeMemory (mem.c:431)
==7958==    by 0x10D472: main (newserver.c:458)
==7958==  Address 0x4a7a788 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 104 alloc'd
==7958==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7958==    by 0x10E13F: safe_malloc (utils.c:7)
==7958==    by 0x10AADC: mem_createFile (mem.c:108)
==7958==    by 0x10BC33: doJob (newserver.c:71)
==7958==    by 0x10CC26: worker (newserver.c:298)
==7958==    by 0x4869608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==7958==    by 0x49A5292: clone (clone.S:95)
==7958== 
Exiting==7958== 
==7958== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7958==     in use at exit: 42 bytes in 1 blocks
==7958==   total heap usage: 46 allocs, 46 frees, 27,179 bytes allocated
==7958== 
==7958== 42 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==7958==    at 0x483DFAF: realloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7958==    by 0x49118C7: _IO_mem_finish (memstream.c:131)
==7958==    by 0x4907FC0: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:57)
==7958==    by 0x10B5B0: freeFile (mem.c:419)
==7958==    by 0x10B32E: mem_remove (mem.c:367)
==7958==    by 0x10B678: mem_removeFile (mem.c:441)
==7958==    by 0x10B61D: freeMemory (mem.c:431)
==7958==    by 0x10D472: main (newserver.c:458)
==7958== 
==7958== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7958==    definitely lost: 42 bytes in 1 blocks
==7958==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7958==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7958==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7958==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7958== 
==7958== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==7958== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I've literaly tried everything,I've even got to remove all memory leaks but still got invalid reads and writes. It's been more then a week and I've just broke my desk from the pure anger.
This is the function that frees a struct element

```
int freeFile(MemFile *file){
    if (file == NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    freeifalloc(file->pathname);
    if(file->fp != NULL){
        fclose(file->fp);
        file->fp = NULL;
    }
    freeifalloc(&(file->buffer));
    //freeifalloc(file->fp->_IO_buf_base);
    //pthread_mutex_destroy(&(file->fileLock));
    freeifalloc(file);
    return 1;
}
```

Send help.

Memfile struct

```
typedef struct fl{

    FILE *fp;
    char *buffer;
    char **addbuffer;
    FILE **addfp;
    char *pathname;
    size_t usedMem;
    int isOpen;
    struct fl *next;
    pthread_mutex_t fileLock;


}MemFile;
```

freeifalloc

```
#define freeifalloc(pointer) if(pointer != NULL) {free(pointer); pointer == NULL;}
```

Comment: What are `MemFile`, `open_memstream` and `freeifalloc` ?

Comment: `file->addbuffer = &fileMemory;` and `ile->addfp = &tmp;` looks suspicious. Are you sure they aren't used after the variables referred become invalid? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There's not enough here to see what you might be doing wrong.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: @MikeCAT they aren't really used, they are there just in case I need to have them, I write and read from FILE * using fread and fwrite

Comment: [open_memstream(3) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html)

Comment: @MikeCAT I know that man page, I already know that after every write I have to fflush and to free memory I have to fclose(filepointer);free(&buf); But it doesn't work

Comment: I've added to the question the definition of Memfile and freeifalloc

Comment: Passing `&fileMemory` for `open_memstream` is also suspicious for usage of dangling pointer. `free(&buf);` is highly suspicious for *undefined behavior* unless `buf` is a macro because `&buf` won't be neither a pointer to buffer allocated via `malloc()` family nor `NULL`.

Comment: `pointer == NULL;` does nothing unless `pointer` is something like `hoge = fuga`.

Comment: @MikeCAT &fileMemory is passed like that because in every example I've seen online, even in the man, they create a pointer to null and pass it by address. I don't know what's suspicious about that. also that free(&buf) was just to mimic what's written in man, the you can see the actual code in the question itself. But that thing about dangling pointer made me think. I can try something. The pointer == NULL was just to flag already free'd memory, I had some problems during develop, and this helped me lol

Comment: `freeifalloc(&(file->buffer));` is wrong because this will pass `&(file->buffer)`, which won't be buffer allocated via `malloc()` family nor `NULL`, to `free()`. What man page had something like `free(&buf);`?

Comment: @MikeCAT my mistake I wasn't right about free(&buf), but still got me thinking, I've read the fmemopen manpage and in the example man uses fmemopen for input and open_memstream for output, I use it for reading and writing, but I'm not sure it's wrong using it for both. Still the problem remains, by my understanding when I fclose, libc does a realloc and when I free the buffer (in a way or other) valgrind spits out invalid read and write

Comment: You shouldn't free things that you didn't allocate. If your number of malloc calls don't correspond to your number of free calls, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Lundin even when they do correspond and memory leaks are 0 i still get invalid read and write from fclose

Comment: So apparently you have some completely unrelated bug...

Comment: Btw `#define freeifalloc(pointer) if(pointer != NULL) {free(pointer); pointer == NULL;}` is complete nonsense. `free()` is well-defined as a no-op if you pass NULL to it. And the silly ==  typo bug should yield compiler warnings. Remove this broken macro and simply write `free(pointer); pointer = NULL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary variables are unnecessary and the source of your problems.

```
//first, allocate your struct
MemFile *file = (MemFile *) safe_malloc(sizeof(MemFile));
//if (!file) error

//you have to zero it out, because in case of an error,
//you probably call the free function, therefore 
//the (pointer) fields have to point to NULL
memset(file, 0, sizeof(MemFile));

file->fp = open_memstream(&file->buffer, &file->usedMem);
//if (!file->fp) error

file->addBuffer = &file->buffer; //what is addBuffer, is this really necessary?
file->addfp = &file->fp; //same here, why?

file->isOpen = 1;
file->next = NULL;

//usedMem is set by open_memstream
//file->usedMem = 0;

//this is also different from your statement
//sizeof(char) equals per standard to 1
file->pathname = (char*) safe_malloc(strlen(pathname)+1);

//there is no no need to set the pointer to NULL
//you free the file anyway, so what's the point?
#define freeifalloc(pointer) if (pointer) free(pointer)

// isn't this much cleaner?
int freeFile(MemFile *file){
    if (!file) 
        return -1;
    
    if (file->pathname)
        free(file->pathname);

    if (file->fp)
        fclose(file->fp);
        
    if (file->buffer)
        free(file->buffer);
        
    if (file)
        free(file);
        
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm implementing it, sir if this works I'm going to cry

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MY GOD YOU SIR ARE D MAN IT SELF IT WORKS HOLY MOLLY WOIWEFOIJ EFPOIQWFPOIQWJ FPOQIJGPOQIERPOQIEGJPQOIERGPQOEIRG JOPQEI, Btw safe_malloc was already 0ing memory :P, also no addBuffer and addfp weren't necesary at all and setting the pointer to null, was just an extra step to be sure I've already freed that memory, but I needed to try everything in order to say "Well I can't find the bug" .From the bottom of my heart,really, thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do with the fields `addBuffer` and `addfp`? I'm curious. But glad it worked out. Btw. `pathname` is in this current state just a reserved buffer, not a string yet.

Comment: "there is no no need to set the pointer to NULL" Well there is if the code is used in a constructor/destructor like pattern and you re-use the same variables over and over. There is however no need to check if the pointer is NULL before calling free(). As foretold in the friendly manual.

Comment: @Erdal Küçük those were because online I've read that when you want to free the buffer from open_memstream you need to have the address itself,it kinda worked out but I still had those invalid read and write,at some point I was so tired to see memory leaks that i've started freeing the buffer from file->fp->_IO_buf_base and thanks to that,leaks where at 0 but still with invalid read and write, those variables were there because after all this I haven't deletted them. In the end I've learned a new thing today and broke a desk. Happy but still, broken desk.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, you're right. I should have stated "In (your) this case, there is no need...", well, even that is not true, because i don't know if that (function) macro is used elsewhere. So correctly: in the function `freeFile` it is unnecessary to set the pointer to NULL after freeing them, since the file structure will be freed anyway.

Comment: It is used somewhere else,infact I had some problems with double freeing memory and setting the pointer to null at the end just worked out, so no complaining. Also there is nothing bad in setting a pointer to null after a free

Comment: @TuttiMarcella Well, technically not but if executed millions or billions times? Therefore, set to NULL when needed, otherwise a free will suffice. But it depends on how smart the compiler is and what optimizations will occur.